# How do I calculate sprites/frame usage on my platform's ram?

Tags: unity, 2d, sprites, performance, mobile

I plan on building a 2d game for mobile and possibly pc. I also plan on using sprites/frames for the animation of my 2d game. What's stopping me from doing so is because I can't figure out if the sprites/frames containing the animation is gonna use up a lot of RAM on my device. Does anybody here know what I'm talking about?

Comment: Use the profiler.

Comment: You know the pixel resolution of your sprite sheet, and the bits per pixel of the texture format you're using, right? How have you tried to calculate the RAM use based on these values?

Comment: No clue yet. I'm just trying to find out if 1 picture(say 200 x 200 for one frame) can effect the RAM(like 4gb of ram on a computer or a mobile device). Can it really effect the RAM?

Comment: actually I need to figure out if a small image like 100kb can affect the ram.